# Change tile size and color in dependence of two different columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to create a geom_tile plot where I want to set the color and the size of the tiles in dependence of two different variables/columns.
I found, that I can use `geom_tile` and `geom_point` together but my code is not generating what I expect (see example code and image). I also know, this is because I use different columns so maybe I need to go a totally different way but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

**Example code**

Generate data:

```
var_1 = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 3)
a = rep("a", 3)
b = rep("b", 3)
c = rep("c", 3)
var_2 = c(a, b, c)

var_3 = c(1, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0.5)
var_4 = c(0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 1)

data_source <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 9, ncol = 4))
data_source$X1 = var_1
data_source$X2 = var_2
data_source$X3 = var_3
data_source$X4 = var_4
```

Create the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
connectivity_plot <- data_source %>% ggplot(
  aes(
    X1,
    X2,
    fill = X3
  )
) +
  geom_tile(
    color = "black",
    lwd = 1.5,
    linetype = 1
  ) +
  geom_point(
    aes(size = X4),
    shape = 19
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "x",
    y = "y"
  ) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    guide = "legend",
    breaks = c(1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 0),
    labels = c("TRUE", "TRUE WITH WARNINGS", "NOT TESTED", "FALSE"),
    colours = c(
      "red",
      "white",
      "yellow",
      "green"
    ),
    values = c(
      0,
      0.5,
      0.75,
      1
    )
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 22, face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
    legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
  ) +
  guides(
    fill = guide_legend(title="WORKS")
  )
```

This is the result of the code:

[image]

So is it possible to connect the `geom_point` part with the `geom_tile` as those are currently plotted independently?

Or in general:

What I would like to receive is that the tiles change in size in dependence of column `X4` (does not work) and change their color in dependence of column `X3` (already works).

P.S.: I tried to add the size to the general `aes` or to the `geom_tile` part but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

With the `size` aes you set the line width of the outline. To change the size of the tile itself you could map on the `width` and `height` aes:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data_source,
  aes(
    X1,
    X2,
    fill = X3
  )
) +
  geom_tile(
    aes(width = X4, height = X4),
    color = "black",
    lwd = 1.5,
    linetype = 1
  ) +
  geom_point(
    aes(size = X4),
    shape = 19
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "x",
    y = "y"
  ) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    guide = "legend",
    breaks = c(1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 0),
    labels = c("TRUE", "TRUE WITH WARNINGS", "NOT TESTED", "FALSE"),
    colours = c(
      "red",
      "white",
      "yellow",
      "green"
    ),
    values = c(
      0,
      0.5,
      0.75,
      1
    )
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 22, face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
    legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
  ) +
  guides(
    fill = guide_legend(title="WORKS")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, forgot you could set the width and height as an aesthetic. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that what you are describing isn't really what `geom_tile`, which by definition is a fixed grid. You can use a filled square point shape instead, using `scale_size_identity`, then add a new size scale for the points using `ggnewscale`:

```r
data_source %>% 
  ggplot(aes(X1, X2, fill = X3)) +
  geom_point(shape = 22, aes(size = X4 * 75)) +
  scale_size_identity() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(guide = "legend",
    breaks  = c(1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 0),
    labels  = c("TRUE", "TRUE WITH WARNINGS", "NOT TESTED", "FALSE"),
    colours = c("red", "white", "yellow", "green"),
    values  = c(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale("size") +
  geom_point(aes(size = X4), shape = 19) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "y", fill = "WORKS") +
  theme(axis.text       = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title      = element_text(size = 22, face = "bold"),
        legend.text     = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.title    = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
        legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 22, size = 10)))
```

[image]

Comment: Also a nice solution. And looks better than my output via "reprex". :D Would suggest to use `key_glyph = "rect"` though to get the fill colors displayed in the legend.

Comment: Just realized that @stefan - thanks. Fixed via `guides`, though of course `key_glyph` would work too.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. I just realized that this is maybe suboptimal for the viewer so I wanted to use a different style. I thought about to display one tile with two colors (actually the same green, yellow etc.). I tried with two `geom_tile` while adjusting the `width` of the second `geom_tile`. This works in general but the issue is that the tiles is centered. Is it possible to right align the tiles somehow? Maybe I need to open another question as this a different topic.